# Assigning multiple conditions to while, but turnoff if one is fufilled

Tags: while-loop

I'm writing this:

```
while (value2 >= 10.00) {
        value2 = value2 - 10.00;        
tendollarbills2 = tendollarbills2 - 1; //Ten dollar bills
```

And getting *this.*

```
How much do you owe?
23.00
You have 0 tens, 6 fives, 4 ones, 7 quarters, 8 dimes, 4 nickels and 9 pennies. 
You now have -2 tens, 6 fives, 1 ones, 7 quarters, 8 dimes, 4 nickels and 9 pennies.
```

Obviously, I don't want -2 tens when I can pay all that with 4 of my 6 fives. Why owe you twenty bucks I have still? No person would ever say, "Oh, you can owe me 20 bucks even though you have that in fives there."

So my idea in English is:

*While you have more than or equal to ten bucks owed,* and *have more than ten bucks, pay a ten!*

But also,

*While you have more than or equal to ten bucks owed* or *you're not out of fives, pay a ten!*

So what I want to know, because I can't find it anywhere on the web or here, is how to make it so that either one will stop the loop.

I am aware of ||, tried it, it doesn't work, like it should, like this:

```
while (value2 >= 10.00) || (tendollarbills2 > 0) {
        value2 = value2 - 10.00;        
tendollarbills2 = tendollarbills2 - 1; //Ten dollar bills
```

Answer (score 0):

make your code an infinite while loop.
instead of `while (value2 >= 10.00) || (tendollarbills2 > 0)`
use `if (value2 >= 10.00) || (tendollarbills2 > 0)`

make the infinite while false when you need to get out of the loop.
hope this might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting an if statement inside your while loop to check whether you have greater then 0 ten dollar bills?

Answer (score 0):

You must put your `tendollarbills2 = tendollarbills2 - 1;` inside your loop.
Also use a `&&`(and) operand, since you want to reduce the amount you owe when you owe more than 10 AND have enough 10 bills

```
while ( value2 >= 10.0 && tendollarbills2 > 0)   
{    
    value2 = value2 - 10.00;    
    tendollarbills2 = tendollarbills2 - 1;   
}
```

Then, create a loop like this for each lower value, one after the other